# Why doesn't home-brew correctly configure my python installation?

Tags: macos, python, homebrew

I installed python 2.7.11 using home-brew on my OS X EI Captain. Note that EI Captain shipped with python 2.7.10 already. However, it seems like the install done by home-brew did't correctly configure the default python. So I typed `python --version` to my console and got `Python 2.7.10`. I can access python 2.7.11 through the IDLE found in the packaged installed by home-brew but not directly through the `python` command in the CLI. How do I fix this issue?